# I want the output as json from the object input, as mentioned below by using for loop

Tags: javascript

By taking a as input want b as output using javascript,

```
    input: var a = {"xyz", "abc", "123"};
    output: [{name: "123"}, {name: "abc"}, {name: "123"}];
```

Comment: Is `a` an `Array`? Why is `"xyz"` not set as a value of an object though `"123"` is set as a value twice? No `for` loop appears at Question.

Comment: Typo error---input: var a = ["xyz", "abc", "123"];
output: [{name: "xyz"}, {name: "abc"}, {name: "123"}];

Comment: `var a = {"xyz", "abc", "123"}` is not a valid `javascript` object. Do you mean `var a = ["xyz", "abc", "123"]`?

Comment: yes var a = ["xyz", "abc", "123"];

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post the javascript code you've written to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var a = ["xyz", "abc", "123"]
let output = a.map( (e) =>  {return {name:e}} )
console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```

Considering you want

```
input: var a = ["xyz", "abc", "123"];
output: [{name: "xyz"}, {name: "abc"}, {name: "123"}];
```

Below is the solution:

```
let output = a.map( (e) => {
        return {"name":e}
})
console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```

Comment: you could shorten it to `a.map(e => ({ name: e }))`

Answer (score 0):

Guess a is an array. If so, i'am recommend to use forEach or map for this purpose.
There is example with for loop.

```js
var a = ["xyz", "abc", "123"],
    newArr=  [];
for(var i = 0; i< a.length; i++){
    newArr.push({name: a[i]})
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(newArr));
```

Comment: it is not returning expected output.